# How to use the full 10-bit PWM resolution (PIC18F2xk22)?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, adc, pwm, c

Hi I am trying to use the full 10-bit PWM resolution for my project, and there is a problem as the duty cycle of the PWM will not set to zero when I rotate the POT to the zero position, here is my code in brief..

```
  CCPR5L= ADRESH;                  
  CCP5CONbits.DC5B1=(ADRESL>>7) & 1; 
  CCP5CONbits.DC5B0=(ADRESL>>6) & 1;
```

I have basically Left adjusted the ADC so that the most significant bits are stored in ADRESH and the 2-LSB are stored in ADRESL. I have tried to copy the 2 LSB bits of ADRESL in to CCP5CON bits (as stated in the datasheet), however it will not set to 0, but if remove :

```
  CCP5CONbits.DC5B1=(ADRESL>>7) & 1; 
  CCP5CONbits.DC5B0=(ADRESL>>6) & 1;
```

and set the bits in

```
CCP5CONbits.DC5B=0b00;
```

to zero PWM works just fine and 0 duty cycle is achieved, but only with 8 bit resolution. Any Ideas on how I could solve this problem ??

Comment: Have you checked that your ADC is actually reading 0 and that the lower 2 bits of ADRESL are actually zero?

Comment: Yes I have checked this

Comment: Have you checked the value in `CCPR5L`and `CCP5CON`with a debugger? This should be the first step.